# SQLAlchemy: proper way to wrap the current session into a model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using declarative_base when constructing my models with SQLalchemy...
so I have a model that looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session                             
engine = create_engine("mysql...")
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)                                         
SessionHeap = scoped_session(session_factory)          
Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base, Actions):                                                      
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'                                                     
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)                                       
    date = Column(Integer)                                                                                                      
    tag = Column(String(50))

class Actions(object):                                                              
    @classmethod                                                                    
    def create(cls, **kwargs):                                                      
        session = SessionHeap()                                                     
        session.add(cls(**kwargs))                                                  
        session.commit()                                                            
        session.close()                                                             
        SessionHeap.remove()                                                        

    def update(self, **kwargs):                                                     
        for key, val in kwargs.iteritems():                                         
            self.__setattr__(key, val)                                              
        session = inspect(self).session                                             
        session.commit()                                                            

    @classmethod                                                                    
    def _search(cls, **kwargs):                                                     
        session = SessionHeap()                                                     
        query = session.query(cls).filter_by(**kwargs)                              
        session.commit()                                                            
        session.close()                                                             
        SessionHeap.remove()                                                        
        return query
```

I'm not sure when I should be calling session.close() or even when to remove the session, and I've been having troubles, especially with queries, where certain sessions do not close and the database gets hung. What is a better pattern for this? (note I want to keep all methods wrapped into the model itself, not in some other global namespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: it's app-specific.

If you're implementing long running process (like a backend daemon), you will probably need to execute multiple commits per session lifespan. If you're working on an HTTP app, the pattern is normally one commit per HTTP request (at the very end, on connection teardown). Most modern web frameworks provide hooks into request setup / teardown. For example, in Flask you can put you session.commit() / session.close() under a method decorated with @app.teardown_request.

I would recommend the following approach:

- (from SQLAlchemy docs) as a general rule, keep the lifecycle of the session separate and external from functions and objects that access and/or manipulate database data. This will greatly help with achieving a predictable and consistent transactional scope.
- replace session.commit() statements above with session.flush() statements. flush() will persist data without committing the transaction. Remove session.close() statements. Remember, session.close() will give the connection back to the Engine / connection pool, it doesn't actually close the connection.
- implement your custom DBRollbackException() exception, use it to rollback current transaction on any error.
- commit once, at the very end (for example, on request teardown)